# Deploying stand-alone jar on Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, jar, war

I've written a sort-of proxy server as desktop application in java (jar). Is there an easy way to convert it to war, so I can deploy it on Tomcat? 
I don't want to add any functionality, there's no need to even handle http requests. I want to run the jar in background, where it will accept sockets.

I've tried using gradle, but seems like it doesn't know it should run my main class.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

apply plugin: "war"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Sorry, I know this is a noobish question, I haven't done anything like this before and just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Desktop application and web application solve different use cases. Your desktop app need to have a class with Main method. This is then used by jvm to execute your application. Web applications follow different initialization paradigm, where servlet api is the main way to develop the application. There is no way where your application will run as web app without modification. A simple way is to create one servlet and have similar code in init method as your main method. Configure that servlet in web.xml and try if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a "WEB-INF" directory to your jar and create a "web.xml" inside. Then rename it to [appname].war and deploy it.

"web.xml" for Tomcat 7 example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app id="ProxyApp" version="3.0" metadata-complete="false" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >
    <display-name>Proxy App</display-name>
</web-app>
```

**Update**

To invoke code at the startup of your app use a ServletContextListener:

```
@WebListener
public class BootInitializer implements ServletContextListener {

 // what to do startup?
 @Override
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("Starting proxy application ...");
    // your main method content here ...
 }

 // what to do shutdown?
 @Override
 public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

 }
}
```

Comment: Well, looks like Tomcat deployed it successfully, but I don't think my main class is running.

Comment: No, because the main class will not be invoked in a server environment, as Mr. Sangram Jadhav already said. I'll make an update.